# Get CGRect coordinates dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, coordinates, cgrect

I'm trying to get the distance between two `UIImageView` on my screen, and for that I planned on substracting the center coordinates of the image 2 (movable) from the image 1 (not movable). 
For that, I need to be able to get dynamically the coordinates of these images and I'm using something like this :

```
    var centerBoardX = CGRectGetMidX(BlackBoard.frame)
    var centerBoardY = CGRectGetMidY(BlackBoard.frame)
    var centerRoundX = CGRectGetMidX(round1.frame)
    var centerRoundY = CGRectGetMidY(round1.frame)

    println(centerBoardX - centerRoundX)
    println(centerBoardY - centerRoundY)
```

But even if I'm moving the image2 all over the screen I always get the same result based on the initial coordinates of both UIImageViews.

What's wrong ? Why do I get only the initial coordinates and not the new ones? 
Thanks !

Comment: Use the debugger to see what is happening, watch the frame as you move the view. Logging can help as well, Also consider [Spark Inspector](http://sparkinspector.com) to see all the views in 3D while you are running the app-there is nothing to add to your app to use it. Perhaps you are not moving the view you think you are.

Comment: maybe check `bounds` instead of `frame` or check `round1.center`? maybe check the `layer` position? It all depends on how you are making the uiimageviews move...

Comment: how are you moving the image view? Through a scroll view? Through a transform? By changing the frame yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I found what was not right. 
My UIImageViews are defined by frames, and I was getting the coordinates of the frame, which are always the same. 
To get the correct coordinates, I needed to get the info from the superview of the object. 
So the working code is

```
var centerBoardX = BlackBoard.superview?.center.x
var centerBoardY = BlackBoard.superview?.center.y
var centerRoundX = Round1.superview?.center.x
var centerRoundY = Round1.superview?.center.y

println(centerBoardX! - centerRoundX!)
println(centerBoardY! - centerRoundY!)
```

And now it's perfectly working !